# Cannot create Aqueduct project from command line

Tags: dart, aqueduct

So I installed the aqueduct package using `pub global activate aqueduct`, and I added the directory of the pub bin to the Path in environment variables. However, when I try to create a new project by typing in `aqueduct create <project-name>`, I receive the following error.

`-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0+1
*** Uncaught error
    Bad state: No element
  **** Stacktrace
  * #0      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:150:5)
  * #1      CLIAqueductGlobal.aqueductPackageRef (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:342:10)
  * #2      CLIAqueductGlobal.templateDirectory (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:347:12)
  * #3      CLIAqueductGlobal.getTemplateLocation (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:351:12)
  * #4      CLITemplateCreator.handle (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/create.dart:51:27)
  * #5      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:159:20)
  * <asynchronous suspension>
  * #6      CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:135:12)
  * #7      main (file:///C:/Users/Zisei/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/aqueduct-3.3.0+1/bin/aqueduct.dart:9:27)
  * #8      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
  * #9      _RawReceivePortImpl`

What's the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

same problem face me
some friend  told me to do that .
first uninstall dart-sdk
then install choco search in web how to install
then run this commend line
choco install dart-sdk --version=2.7.1
you must install version 2.7.1
that it
same problem face me
some friend  told me to do that